# Error: The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, iis-8

I have an application , there I am consuming one service to update my record . I have hosted this application in a server. The application is working fine if I access with in the system (http://sysytem/test/home.aspx). The problem here is, if I am trying access the same url from any other system in the same network it's throwing The  error : HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'.